# How to get file where function is defined if you only have a class that the function is bounded to?

Tags: python, function

I have a function (`foo`) and a class (`Bar`) that takes in a function as an attribute `func`.

if I pass in `foo` to an instance of `Bar` it's able to determine that `func` is a `foo` i.e.

```
def foo():
     pass

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, func):
         self.func = func

c = Bar(foo)

print(c.func.__name__)
>> foo

print(c.func)
>> <function foo at 0x7ffa86063290>
```

If foo is defined in a separate file than Bar is it possible to extract the `__file__` of where foo is defined?

I tried:

```
print(c.func.__file__)
```

but got:

```
`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__file__'`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found what I needed in the `inspect` module:

```
print(inspect.getfile(c.func))
```